# 32 bit WPF .NET app can't find its 32 bit dll

Tags: c++, wpf, assembly, x86, masm

I use P/Invoke, not C++/CLI and am working on Visual Studio 2017.
My app is WPF.NET – 32 bit, written in C#. The app loads successfully its 32-bit DLL when I run it on my PCx64, but it crashes when I run it on a virtual machine (64 or 32). I think couldn't add the DLL...and don't know why.
My DLL is written on C++ and includes a class, with some functions written on Assembler. May be the problem comes from it?

MyClass.cpp:

```
int MyClass::Foo_1()  
{  
    __asm  
  {  
    mov eax, 0  
  }
}  
void MyClass::SetFoo_1()  
{  
  resultEAX = new int;  
  int a = -1;  
  try  
  {  
    a = Foo_1();  
  }  
  catch (int e) { }  
  if (a == 0) {  
  *resultEAX = 0;  
  }  
  else {  
    *resultEAX = 1;  
  }  
}
```

MyClass.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H  
#define MYCLASS_H  
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass {  
public:  
    int * resultEAX ;  
    int Foo1();  
    void SetFoo_1();  
    int  GetEAX();  
};  
#endif
```

MyClassCaller.h:

```
extern "C" {  
#endif  
__declspec(dllexport) MyClass* Create();  
__declspec(dllexport) void Dispose(MyClass* a_pObject);  
__declspec(dllexport) void SetFoo_1(MyClass* a_pObject);  
__eclspec(dllexport) int GetEAX(MyClass* a_pObject);  
#ifdef __cplusplus
}  
#endif
```

MyClassCaller.cpp:

```
Graphics* Create()  
{  
  return new MyClass();  
}  

void Dispose(MyClass * a_pObject)  
{  
  if (a_pObject != NULL)  
  {  
    delete a_pObject;  
    a_pObject = NULL;  
  }  
}  

void SetFoo_1(MyClass * a_pObject)  
{  
  if (a_pObject != nullptr)  
  {  
    a_pObject->SetFoo_1();  
  }  
}  

int GetEAX(MyClass * a_pObject)  
{  
  if (a_pObject != NULL)  
  {  
     return a_pObject->GetEAX();  
  }  
  return 0;  
}
```

And I call the class from WPF.NET using managed C# code:

```
IntPtr pMyClass = MyClassHandling.Create();  
Int32 a = 0;  
Int64 b = 0;  
long c = 0;  
long rslt = 0;  

try  
{  
  MyClassHandling.SetFoo_1(pMyClass);  
  if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)  
  {  
    //"SysWOW64"  
    b = MyClassHandling.GetEAX(pMyClass);  
   //……  
  }  
  else  
  {  
    //"system32"  
    a = pMyClassHandling.GetEAX(pGraphics);  
    //…  
  }  

MyClassHandling.Dispose (pGraphics); 
pMyClass = IntPtr.Zero;  

[DllImport("SomeAssemblerFunctions.dll")]  
static public extern IntPtr Create();  
[DllImport("SomeAssemblerFunctions.dll")]  
static public extern void Dispose(IntPtr pGraphicsObject);  
[DllImport("SomeAssemblerFunctions.dll", EntryPoint = "SetGraphicMode1")]  
static public extern void SetFoo_1(IntPtr pGraphicsObject);  
[DllImport("SomeAssemblerFunctions.dll", EntryPoint = "GetEAX")]  
static public extern int GetEAX(IntPtr pGraphicsObject);
```